# Assigning times to events

Tags: minizinc

```
   include "globals.mzn";
   %Data
   time_ID = [11,12,13,14,15];
   eventId = [0011, 0012, 0013, 0021, 0022, 0031, 0041, 0051, 0061, 0071];
   int:ntime = 5;
   int:nevent = 10;
   set of int: events =1..nevent;
   set of int: time = 1..ntime;
   array[1..nevent] of int:eventId;
   array[1..nevent] of var time:event_time;
   array[1..ntime] of int:time_ID;
   solve satisfy;
   constraint
   forall(event in eventId)(
   exists(t in time_ID)(
   event_time[event] = t ));
   output[ show(event_time) ];
```

I'm trying to assign times to an event using the code above. 
But rather than randomly assign times to the events, it returns an error " array access out of bounds" 
How can I make it select randomly from the time array?
Thank you

Comment: When I run this model it (with MiniZinc 2.0.10) I get an UNSATISFIABLE result, not an error. How do you run it? Also, this is not the complete model since time_ID is not declared correctly. Can you add all missing parts of the model?

Comment: I have updated the code, I missed out the line where I declared the time_ID. I run it by using the run button on my IDE. It gives me errors on the "forall and exists". Thank you

Comment: I still don't get the error your report, just UNSATISFIABLE. But I guess that you mean something like this constraint where the indices in the "forall" and "exists" are integers starting from 1: 
constraint forall(event in events) ( exists(t in time) ( event_time[event] = t));

Comment: Okay, this is the error report MiniZinc:                                                  flattening error: 
"C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/testevent.mzn:16:
  in call 'forall'
  in array comprehension expression
    with event = 11
    with t = 11
C:/Users/user/OneDrive/Documents/testevent.mzn:17:
  in binary '=' operator expression
  in array access
  array access out of bounds". I tried the code in your comment, but it just assigns the time at the first index to all the events. Thanks

Comment: The error was because you tried to assign the index 11 (the first element in eventId array) in "event_time" array. 

The assigment of just 1's is correct since you haven't done any other constraints on the "event_time" array. If you set the number of solutions to - say - 3 you will see other solutions. And, in fact, the constraint as it stand now is not really meaningful since it just ensures that there is some assignment to the elements in "event_time", but this constraint is handled by the domain of "event_time" (i.e. that all indices are in the range 1..ntime).

Comment: Oh okay, thank you so much. I will add more constraints

Comment: I will copy my last answer into a formal answer, go you can approve and close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because you tried to assign the index 11 (the first element in eventId array) in "event_time" array.

The assigment of just 1's is correct since you haven't done any other constraints on the "event_time" array. If you set the number of solutions to - say - 3 you will see other solutions. And, in fact, the constraint as it stand now is not really meaningful since it just ensures that there is some assignment to the elements in "event_time", but this constraint is handled by the domain of "event_time" (i.e. that all indices are in the range 1..ntime).